# Ionic Please provide a valid ISO 8601 datetime format datetime issue

Tags: javascript, datetime, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to bind my Ionic DateTime component through ngModel. I get a value from backend which looks like this

```
"30-07-2021 12:00:00 AM"
```

Then I process it into -

```js
var date = "30-07-2021 12:00:00 AM"
var finalDate = date.split(" ")[0].split("-");
var fdate =
  finalDate[2] +
  "-" +
  finalDate[1] +
  "-" +
  finalDate[0];
var ISOdate =  new Date(fdate).toISOString() 
console.log(ISOdate);
```

and I get an error
"Error parsing date: "2021-07-30T00:00:00.000Z". Please provide a valid ISO 8601 datetime format"

What am I doing wrong here?

Here is my datetime component-

```
<ion-datetime
  (ionChange)="onChange(filters.DTO_Property_Name,$event,filters.Data_Type_Enum)"
   cancelText="Clear"
   (ionCancel)="clear(filters.Filter_Name)"
   [(ngModel)]="myDateValues[filters.Filter_Name]"
   displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY"
    >
</ion-datetime>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More comment than answer.

You're parsing a string like "30-07-2021 12:00:00 AM" by firstly parsing and reformatting it as "2021-07-30 12:00:00 AM" then using the built–in parser. That's not a good idea as the string isn't in a format supported by ECMA-262 so parsing is implementation dependent.

The string should be treated as local, so:

```
new Date(fdate).toISOString();
```

should not produce a timestamp like "2021-07-30T00:00:00.000Z" unless your offset is +0 or it's being parsed as UTC (it might also return "Invalid Date" or throw a range error). I'll guess that you want it treated as UTC.

Possibly the ionic parser is getting upset about the decimal seconds produced by *toISOString*, so either remove them or don't use *toISOString*.

E.g. just reformat the string, avoiding *Date* and *toISOString*:

```js
// Reformat "30-07-2021 12:00:00 AM" to "2021-07-30T00:00:00Z"
function formatTimestamp(ts) {
  let [D,M,Y,h,m,s,ap] = ts.toLowerCase().split(/\W/);
  h = String(h%12 + (ap == 'am'? 0 : 12)).padStart(2, '0');
  return `${Y}-${M}-${D}T${h}:${m}:${s}Z`;  
}

console.log(formatTimestamp("30-07-2021 12:00:00 AM"));
```